# Can't solve the following Visual 2008

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim a, b, c As Integer
a = 10
b = 3
c = a And b

MessageBox.Show(c)
```

result c=2
how it comes?

Comment: It's **correct**. If you want to make a **sum**, use the **+** operator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP lacks even the very basic, **rudimentary fundamentals** of programming.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I would keep it open so many people can see this even though it is "fundamentals". Many people I refer to, they are just like OP

Answer (score 9):

The [And operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) here uses the

> bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions

```
10 = 1010 
 3 = 0011
---------
     0010 = 2
```

Comment: what a idea. i didn't think.shame on me

Comment: Sorry cannot understand your last comment